# How to Get Bounds and Change Bounds to Remove or add list of Marker Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im Stuck in a situation where i need to get the Bounds and the Change Bounds so i could add and Remove the Marker information on my Added List below my Google Map

Same with the Zoom change, i need to add because im using Marker Manager

I need some help on how to implement this kind because im new to Google Maps

Here's my Codes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var placesList;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });

         placesList = document.getElementById('places');
    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
    function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function (address) {
            $.each(address, function () {
                var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal


                        })
                        placesList.innerHTML += '<li>' + currVal + '</li>';


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);




                }
                else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    setTimeout(codeAddress, 2000);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return false;
}

window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
    codeAddress();
}
```

Heres the Screenshot

[image]

Found a List https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination

I want to Make the List that is inside the Google Maps

Thanks in Advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the location as a property of the `<li>`-elements:

```
$('#places').append($('<li/>')
                      .text(currVal)
                       .data('location',results[0].geometry.location));
```

...then you later be able to iterate over the `<li/>`-elements and use `LatLngBounds.contains()` to check if the bounds contain the location(and hide the `<li>` when it doesn't)

Example:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed',function(){
          $('#places li').css('display',  function(){
              return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
            });
        });
```

Note: at the end of the `$.getJSON`-callback you should trigger the `bounds_changed`-event to apply the filtering of the list:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'bounds_changed');
```

(or apply the filtering directly by setting the display of the elements when you create them)

Comment: i want to add an onchange sir, can you help me with that?

Comment: Added an example above.

Comment: sir im just new to google maps , where should i insert this set of codes. sorry for being newbie :(

Comment: and im having error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lat' of undefined`

Comment: Dr. Molle after trials i removed the error but when it comes to bound, when the last added marker is out of bounds , the whole list of the other marker is also removed

Comment: Dr. Molle I want to ask this , i know its too late but can how can i make it an anchortag the appended `<li>`??